# Can I have two separate files? React.js and HTML file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React.js, and I have noticed that each React file appears to be just a mix of JavaScript and HTML. But I enjoy having distinct files for my HTML and JS. So, I am wondering if I can have these two independent files but also include a link (or something) in either the HTML or JS file, so that they may communicate with one another.

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to look into the following pattern as a way to keep your code organized. React isn't designed to have the HTML/JSX in literally its own file without any JS code, but I find that using this pattern works well to achieve good separation of concerns:
https://www.patterns.dev/posts/presentational-container-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

React components implement a render() method that takes input data and returns what to display. This example uses an XML-like syntax called JSX. Input data that is passed into the component can be accessed by render() via this.props.

In other words, it was more simple than we separate html and render it on React, as a component.

If we still want to access html page via any page that created with react, we can did it via a href.

For any other way like import it (maybe), i think it was too complicated because of some reason.

Hope you will more understand about react with this [react docs link](https://reactjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

**React** is used to build `single-page applications` which is an application that loads a **single HTML page** and all the necessary assets (such as JavaScript and CSS) required for the application to run . this **single HTML page** is  `index.html` located in the public folder (if you're using create-react-app)